# C++ primer TextQuery program

Tags: c++

Hello I have this simple example from C++ primer  ed.

"
Exercises Section 15.9.1

Exercise 15.31: Given that s1, s2, s3, and s4 are all strings, determine
what objects are created in the following expressions:

```
(a) Query(s1) | Query(s2) & ~ Query(s3);
(b) Query(s1) | (Query(s2) & ~ Query(s3));
(c) (Query(s1) & (Query(s2)) | (Query(s3) & Query(s4)));
```

"

And I've seen the solution as:

"

- (a) `Query(s1) | Query(s2) & ~ Query(s3);`
- (b) `Query(s1) | (Query(s2) & ~ Query(s3));`
- (c) `(Query(s1) & (Query(s2)) | (Query(s3) & Query(s4)));`
- (a): `WordQuery` -> `NotQuery` -> `AndQuery` -> `OrQuery`
- (b): `WordQuery` -> `NotQuery` -> `AndQuery` -> `OrQuery` (same as the previous one)
- (c): `WordQuery` -> `AndQuery` -> `OrQuery`

"

But what I think in A: the result is an AndQuery not OrQuery because Logical operators are left-to-right so `Query(s1) | Query(s2)` is evaluated first yielding an OrQuery then this Query is used with an AndQuery: (OrQuery & ~Query(s3)).

- In B it is OK because and the result is an OrQuery: Query(s1) | AndQury and the result is an OrQuery becuase we used parenthesis to change precedence.

So can anyone help me to explain this exercise and whether my guesses are correct?

Thank you!

Comment: AND is actually higher precedence than OR.  Have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: Oh sorry my bad!! I've forgotten that and thought they are equal! Thank you very much bro!